# Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate asks for Product Key

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am trying to install Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate.

I have configured a Raid (Intel Matrix Storage Manager) (Ctrl+I at boot) on a z8na-d6 motherboard. Raid0 of two 120gb disks.

Installing from USB drive, install loads fine. I select language, Install Now, waiting for setup is starting.

Popup says the product key entered does not match any of the windows images available for installation, enter a different product key.  (I havent entered any and havent got any. I got the install disk from the dreamspark program).

Comment: To be clear, are you using the Release Candidate?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate from Dreamspark program (access from cambus network).

Comment: I tried to install a few hours ago where i did not get this error, but an error about a missing media drive driver. So i wanted to start over to create this post, but this time i only got to the point i outlined here.

Comment: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate Datacenter 64-bit

Comment: Dude, ge the released version. It is out now.

Comment: Where ? and can that be the case for the key not working?

Comment: Think @TomTom is trolling

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you contacted them about this problem?

Comment: I have only mailed them and waiting for reply. But the problem are resolved now. Must be some incurrupt files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you got a bad disk image from wherever you got it. You can [obtain a clean ISO image directly from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/subscriptions/securedownloads/#FileId=49272). (Login with the same credentials you signed up for DreamSpark with.)

It could also be that something is wrong with your DVD drive. Try verifying the media after you burn your DVD.

Comment: I am downloading a new disk. I assume i will end up with the same error i got earlier then, about missing media drive driver. If thats the case i will create a new question for that.

Comment: Downloaded a new one and its the same problem

Comment: Try verifying the media....

Comment: How? Downloaded the iso from two different places with same result.

Comment: and i am using a usb drive

Comment: Got it to work by erasing everything on the drive